# can i use highlighted the table view cell without default blue color in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I doing a project where i need to use highlighted table view color not default.

Answer (score 9):

Of course you can.

There are two methods to achieve this:

1. Use `UITableViewCell`'s `selectedBackgroundView` and `selectedTextColor` properties
2. Subclass `UITableViewCell` and implement the `drawInRect` and `setSelected:animated:` methods

The latter option gives you more flexibility and much better performance, but it might be slightly harder if you haven't used CoreGraphics before.

**UPDATE** In response to the OP's comment:

Here's how you can use the `selectedBackgroundView` property:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
[bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgView];
[bgView release];
```

I haven't tried this myself, but it should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first method?  I tried `cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` but it didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to [this demo](http://code.google.com/p/table-group-cell-background-color-demo/) - maybe you could have a look at it and get some help.