# How to change the default blue color when selecting the row of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

#### Duplicate:

> [can i use highlighted the table view cell without default blue color in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733095/can-i-use-highlighted-the-table-view-cell-without-default-blue-color-in-objective)

How can I change the default blue color when selecting the row of UITable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i use highlighted the table view cell without default blue color in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733095/can-i-use-highlighted-the-table-view-cell-without-default-blue-color-in-objectiv)

Answer (score 4):

UITableViewCellSelectionStyle is built in to Cocoa Touch and will give you a few choices.  For more customization, you'll need to change your cell manually:

[How do I set UITableViewCellSelectionStyle property to some custom color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260523/how-do-i-set-uitableviewcellselectionstyle-property-to-some-custom-color)

Answer (score 0):

in the delegate of the tableview, where you create the cell, you can custom it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"customCellIdentifier ";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourBackground.png"]] autorelease];
    }

    // configure the cell
}
```